# How can I query multiple related tables, without a join, and get consistent data using JDBC?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, jdbc, transactions

I am creating a process that connects to a given SQL Server database via JDBC, scans every table, and reads any new data that has been inserted or updated since the last run of this process. The owner of the database will not allow this process to do joins on any of the tables due to performance concerns.

**The scenario in question**

- Table A is a parent of table B
- This process reads data from Table A
- Prior to the process reading Table B, a new parent record is inserted
  into Table A and new child records are inserted into Table B
- When Table B is read, there will be child records present that don't
  have a corresponding parent record in the result set from the
  previous read of Table A

**How can I query multiple related tables, without a join, and get consistent data using JDBC?**

Comment: Are you able to use a service that can process the data such as ASP.NET?

Comment: I'm using JAVA 8 and connecting via JDBC

Comment: ROFL. They will not allow joins because of performance concerns but they are ok with reading every row of every table? This makes absolutely no sense at all. They are preventing accessing data in a standard way because it could impact performance yet allow a non-standard way which absolutely will negatively impact performance. Somebody needs to talk to this person and ask them where they came up with this stupid notion.

Comment: The process will not be reading every row. A last modified timestamp column will be used to determine what has changed since the last run.

Comment: Even so the bizarre enforcement of not using join is one of the strangest things I have heard of.

Comment: I do not disagree, but it's the scenario I've been given. These databases are already slammed with volume from other sources and this process will run on a somewhat frequent basis (every couple minutes). That's the justification I was given for not using joins.

Comment: Well since you can't get the data out in a sensible method you are going to be stuck using RBAR logic here. You will have to retrieve all the parent rows that you need. Then you will have to loop through them one by one and run a separate query against the child table for each parent row. So much for the performance "benefit" of not using joins. Or maybe you can use a stored procedure and a table valued parameter to get the child data. But I suspect that would be outlawed also.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot do JOINs, you probably then just have to keep track of each retrieved primary key of each parent table and then use those for querying the child rows. It will complexify the queries, and add more strain to the DB, as you're executing more queries vs doing it in a single JOINed query, but it should give the same results.